# iOS: Buttons spaced equally using Autolayout/Storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have 5 buttons that I would like to space evenly across the bottom of the screen when my app is in landscape orientation. Can I achieve this using constraints in the Storyboard? I've seen other answers that involve creating constraints in code, and I'd like to avoid this if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create bottom bar and add five buttons and five spacers between them. I found this image on Google for you:

[image]